# Countable choice in $L(\mathbb{R}^*_G)$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals, determinacy

Let $\lambda$ be a singular strong limit cardinal and let $G \subset \text{Col}(\omega,\mathord{<}\lambda)$ be a $V$-generic filter.  Let $\mathbb{R}^*_G = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} \mathbb{R}^{V[G \restriction \alpha]}$.  Then countable choice fails in $V(\mathbb{R}^*_G)$, even for reals: $\omega_1$ is $\lambda$, which is singular.  On the other hand, $\mathsf{CC}_\mathbb{R}$ can hold in $L(\mathbb{R}^*_G)$: for example if $\lambda$ is a limit of Woodin cardinals then $L(\mathbb{R}^*_G)$ satisfies the Axiom of Determinacy, which implies $\mathsf{CC}_\mathbb{R}$.
In fact we then get $\mathsf{CC}$ in $L(\mathbb{R}^*_G)$ because everything is $\text{OD}$ from a real.  But the large cardinal hypothesis seems like it may be overkill.  So my question is:

> What is the consistency strength of the statement "$\lambda$ is a singular strong limit cardinal and Countable Choice holds in $L(\mathbb{R}^*_G)$"?

As far as I know, it could be consistent relative to $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but I only see how to get it from infinitely many Woodin cardinals.

Comment: It must be at least $0^\sharp$ because if $\lambda$ is a singular cardinal and Jensen's covering holds, then $\lambda$ is singular in $L$.

Comment: I always thought that the trick was to collapse the Woodin cardinals, not everything. You might think there is no difference, but there is. Compare the Feferman-Levy model to Truss models.

Comment: @Monroe Oh, quite right.  And it looks like every bounded subset of $\lambda$, and hence every real in $\mathbb{R}^*_G$, has a sharp for the same reason.  To go further and get an inner model with a Woodin cardinal, we could try the same thing with $K$ instead of $L$.  But I'm not sure how that would work, because we used (full) covering for $L$ to get sharps and $K$ may only satisfy weak covering (as far as I know.)

Comment: Also, the first thing I'd try is to shoot a Prikry to a measurable and collapse.

Comment: @Asaf Aha, that does seem to show that it follows from a measurable.  Prikry forcing doesn't change $\mathbb{R}^*_G$, so it doesn't change $L(\mathbb{R}^*_G)$.  And because $\lambda$ was measurable (hence inaccessible) to begin with, $L(\mathbb{R}^*_G) \models \mathsf{DC}$.  So together with Monroe's comment this shows that the consistency strength is between a measurable and "every real has a sharp."

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable claim. My guess is that a measurable is right on the money.

Comment: @Asaf I think you are right, because the core model below a measurable satisfies the strong form of covering if I recall correctly.  But now, unlike with $L$, one has to consider where the core model is constructed.  I will think about this.

Comment: Trevor, we already know that $\lambda$ is regular in $L$ (and so in other inner models). Maybe some sort of a Mathias theorem would work here. Consider a sequence witnessing the singularity of $\lambda$, and construct a measure in an inner model.

Comment: Trevor, any luck on proving that if $L(\Bbb R^*_G)$ satisfies countable choice then $\omega_1$ is measurable in some inner model? Perhaps you could also show directly that $\omega_1$ is measurable in that model,  it might work.

Comment: @Yair I will have to think some more about why there would be no partial extenders on $K$ between $\lambda$ and $\lambda^+$.  The part after that seems right to me, although some people get nervous about constructing core models without AC, so I guess there is something to check.

Comment: @Asaf I agree; it does seem plausible that $\omega_1$ itself would be measurable in some inner model; it's true in the example obtained by Prikry forcing and also in the example where $\lambda$ is a limit of Woodins (because $\mathsf{AD}$ implies $\omega_1$ is measurable in $\text{HOD}$.)  So maybe the hypothesis of the question implies that $\lambda$ is measurable in $\text{HOD}^{L(\mathbb{R}^*_G)}$.